# how can i contact us page to django

Tags: html, django, backend, contacts

Save all the contact us inputs on the database, and create a view to handle all the
records. Tasks include
Search and sort: based on the user entries like the services, or the
email, phone number, names etc.
Delete: records with irrelevant information to be
removed/fake/false records to be removed
Insert:: new records to be inserted when a new entry is submitted

how to perform these tasks

Answer (score 0):

You should create a model and define the fields in question here. You can use the django admin panel to organize the records, it gives sorting and searching by default. You can detect fake records by sending an e-mail to the entered e-mail address. I have no idea how you can do this with a phone number.